# Copying file using Apache Commons FileUtils

Tags: java, file, apache-commons

On the first run, I want to copy the given `File` to a new location with a new file name.

Every subsequent run should overwrite the same destination file created during first run.

During first run, the destination file does not exist. Only the directory exists.

I wrote the following program:

```
package myTest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class FileCopy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestFileCopy fileCopy = new TestFileCopy();
        File sourceFile = new File("myFile.txt");
        fileCopy.saveFile(sourceFile);
        File newSourceFile = new File("myFile_Another.txt");
        fileCopy.saveFile(newSourceFile);
    }
}

class TestFileCopy {
    private static final String DEST_FILE_PATH = "someDir/";
    private static final String DEST_FILE_NAME = "myFileCopied.txt";

    public void saveFile(File sourceFile) {
        URL destFileUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(DEST_FILE_PATH
                + DEST_FILE_NAME);
        try {
            File destFile = Paths.get(destFileUrl.toURI()).toFile();
            FileUtils.copyFile(sourceFile, destFile);
        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

However, this throws null pointer exception on the following line:

```
File destFile = Paths.get(destFileUrl.toURI()).toFile();
```

What am I missing?
Directory `someDir` is directly under my project's root directory in eclipse. 
Both source files `myFile.txt` and `myFile_Another.txt` exists directly under my project's root directory in eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this and it works as I am expecting:

```
public void saveFile1(File sourceFile) throws IOException {
        Path from = sourceFile.toPath();
        Path to = Paths.get(DEST_FILE_PATH + DEST_FILE_NAME);
        Files.copy(from, to, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
```

Using Java `nio`.